# Refreshing a page from the click of a menuitem

Tags: java, zk

I have a zul page with a list of menuitems pointing to different zul pages. I would like that, when a menu item is clicked, the page pointed out by that menuitem has to be refreshed. I have tried with the Events.sendEvent() approach, but it doesn't work. What's the best approach to do it? Thanks in advance. here is the code:

```
  <menuitem id="Car" label="Car">
          <attribute name="onClick">
              {
                 inc.setSrc("/zul/car.zul");
                 Events.sendEvent(reload, event);
              }
          </attribute>
   </menuitem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<include />` for zul pages better do it like this:

```
...
<div id="currentSite" width="800px" heigth="600px" /> 
...
```

and then add `onClick` listeners in java, btw don't use scripts like yours in production.

```
@Listen("onClick = #Car")
public void carClicked(Event ev){
   // clear old content
   currentSite.getChildren().clear();
   // add the new
   Executions.createComponent("/zul/car.zul", currentSite, null);
}
```

You have more control and less pain ;)